# Different probabilities in an exercise

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

I've got this following problem solved.

A monkey is given 12 blocks: 3 shaped like squares, 3 like rectangles, 3 like triangles, and 3 like circles. If it draws three of each kind in order- say, 3 triangles, then 3 squares, and so on- Calculate the probability of this event.

The answer for this is event is following:

`P (Each kind is drawn in order) = 4!⋅3!⋅3!⋅3!⋅3! / 12! = 6.5E-5`

---

There, the order matters. If the order *doesn't matter*, I have to use combination?

Could someone, please, explain me?

Comment: This looks correct to me. The total number of orders of 4 "sets" is $4!$. The total number of orders of the 12 shapes is $\dfrac{12!}{(3!)^4}$. So, the total probability is $\dfrac{4!}{\left(\dfrac{12!}{(3!)^4}\right)}$

Comment: When determining whether you want to treat order as relevant or not for the purposes of deciding on a sample space, you should first look to see if the event or events you are trying to calculate probabilities of make direct reference to the order in which things occur.  Here, absolutely, it is talking about order being relevant so we *must* treat order as relevant in our calculations.  In other examples it could be the case that it doesn't matter in which case we have the option of treating it as relevant or as not relevant based on our preferences to make calculations easier.

Comment: So, it's not make sense If I suppose for this exercise, the order does not matter? For example, let's suppose, the same shape figures have same size, but different to the other figures. I mean, triangles are bigger than circles. So the monkey can identify them when he's going to draw them. The probability would be the same?